# create mail account on server via php

Tags: php, email

i have programmed small mail reader script

and linked it with my website script

My question is

i want allow my website users to make them mail on my server

IMAP email on my domain

Question is:

How to create email on server via php

i searched in imap library and found no thing

thank you and sorry for my language!

Comment: Unless you're using virtual accounts, an imap account on a server is a system account (e.g. a full-blown login). You probably don't want to give any of your scripts the kind of system access required to create an account.

Comment: This depends entirely on your server and what mail platform you are using. How would you do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on your configuration. I, for example, use Postfix with Dovecot and have MySQL store the users. If I want to add a user, I simply run `INSERT INTO MAIL.USERS ('un@domain', ENCRYPT('password'))`. I got a couple of different sets of instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/286690/i-need-a-help-with-centos-webmail-configuration).

Of course, this was for CentOS, so you may need to do a bit more research.

Comment: My os system is centos and i have successfully installed postfix but here is small problem in (mailx) i should send an welcome mail via mailx to complite mail building! how i can send mail by mailx via php ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = 'adduser user1';

exec($str);
```

Comment: This won't work unless PHP is running as root. And we'd better hope PHP is not running as root!